# How to show multiple images through their URL

Tags: android

I want to get the images through the URL into my project, I have multiple images to show in my project and I am having the image URL also. I want to display the images as the page flip or pressed by the next button by the URL of images. I know how to show one image through URL with Picasso library but showing multiple images I am not able to do that, so help me to do that as I am new to android.

Here is my code and I am showing images with curl view effect...help me here to show the images through url..

```
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Rect;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
    import java.util.Objects;

    public class Braids extends AppCompatActivity {

CurlView cv;
int index=0;
String type;
String abcd[]={"https://imgur.com/zSX6k5m.png","https://imgur.com/Xhjz9HC.png","https://imgur.com/8hOKrBf"};
ImageView img;
private int[] mBitmapIds;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_braids);

    cv = (CurlView) findViewById(R.id.curls);
    type=getIntent().getExtras().getString("CheckShirt");
    if(type.equals("braids")){

        for(int i=0;i<abcd.length;i++)
        {
                //printing url
        }
}
    else if(type.equals("buns"))
{
    mBitmapIds= new int[]{};
}
    else if (type.equals("fallinghairs"))
{
    mBitmapIds=new int[]{};
}
    cv.setPageProvider(new PageProvider());
    cv.setSizeChangedObserver(new SizeChangedObserver());
    cv.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
    cv.setCurrentIndex(index);
    cv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    cv.setAllowLastPageCurl(false);


}

private class SizeChangedObserver implements CurlView.SizeChangedObserver {
    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h) {

        if (w > h) { cv.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_TWO_PAGES);
        }

        else {

            cv.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_ONE_PAGE);

        }
    }
}

private class PageProvider implements CurlView.PageProvider {

    // Bitmap resources.


    @Override
    public int getPageCount() {
       return mBitmapIds.length;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") private Bitmap loadBitmap(int width, int height, int index) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);




        b.eraseColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(mBitmapIds[index]);

        int margin = 0;
        int border = 0;
        Rect r = new Rect(margin, margin, width - margin, height - margin);

        int imageWidth = r.width() - (border * 2);
        int imageHeight = imageWidth * d.getIntrinsicHeight()
                / d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        if (imageHeight > r.height() - (border * 2)) {
            imageHeight = r.height() - (border * 2);
            imageWidth = imageHeight * d.getIntrinsicWidth()
                    / d.getIntrinsicHeight();
        }


        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(0xFFC0C0C0);
        c.drawRect(r, p);
        r.left += border;
        r.right -= border;
        r.top += border;
        r.bottom -= border;

        d.setBounds(r);
        d.draw(c);

        return b;
    }



    @Override
    public void updatePage(CurlPage page, int width, int height, int index) {


        Bitmap front = loadBitmap(width, height, index);
        page.setTexture(front, CurlPage.SIDE_BOTH);
        page.setColor(Color.argb(127, 255, 255, 255), CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);



    }

}
```

}

Comment: POst what you have tried so far

Comment: Make an array of ImageUrl and then on swipe or next button pressed pass next array index.!

Comment: you can load one image from url then on next button press pass next image url to Picasso and load the next image on demand.not preload all images.

Comment: I have edit my problem with the code now please help me to get the image.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display in the same page you can use Facebook Fresco.

- [Github link](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)
- [Documentation](http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Glide library.
According to your problem you can use the following reference 
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/ . Hope this will help you.